# Steps are not included in report

Tags: reporting, specflow

I'm creating reports, but steps are not included (look at screenshoot in the end of question!).

1. I've created ClassLibrary1 project in VS15
2. I've added NUnit3, NUnitConsole, Specflow and Specflow.NUnit nuget packages.
3. I've added defaul feature and step definition files.

After that, I ran these commands from cmd(first from nunit folder, second from specflow folder):

```
nunit3-console.exe --labels=All --out=TestResult.txt "--result=TestResult.xml;format=nunit2" D:\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll

specflow.exe nunitexecutionreport D:\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj /out:MyResult.html
```

As I see, steps are not included in output HTML file... I remember that it was working in previous versions, and i saw examples with button like 'expand', which should help to see exact steps been performed in scenario.
What do i miss?

TestResult.txt is

```
=> ClassLibrary1.SpecFlowFeature1Feature.AddTwoNumbers
Given I have entered 50 into the calculator
-> pending: StepDefinition1.GivenIHaveEnteredSomethingIntoTheCalculator(50)
And I have entered 70 into the calculator
-> skipped because of previous errors
When I press add
-> skipped because of previous errors
Then the result should be 120 on the screen
-> skipped because of previous errors
```

TestResult.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!--This file represents the results of running a test suite-->
<test-results name="D:\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll" total="1" errors="0" failures="0" not-run="0" inconclusive="1" ignored="0" skipped="0" invalid="0" date="2017-02-28" time="12:37:46">
  <environment nunit-version="3.5.0.0" clr-version="4.0.30319.42000" os-version="Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0" platform="Win32NT" cwd="D:\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.6.0\tools" machine-name="DESKTOP-417JV6U" user="dom" user-domain="DESKTOP-417JV6U" />
  <culture-info current-culture="en-US" current-uiculture="en-US" />
  <test-suite type="Assembly" name="D:\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.386" asserts="0">
    <properties>
      <property name="_PID" value="25444" />
      <property name="_APPDOMAIN" value="domain-" />
    </properties>
    <results>
      <test-suite type="TestSuite" name="ClassLibrary1" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.379" asserts="0">
        <results>
          <test-suite type="TestFixture" name="SpecFlowFeature1Feature" description="SpecFlowFeature1" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.378" asserts="0">
            <properties>
              <property name="Description" value="SpecFlowFeature1" />
            </properties>
            <results>
              <test-case name="ClassLibrary1.SpecFlowFeature1Feature.AddTwoNumbers" description="Add two numbers" executed="True" result="Inconclusive" success="False" time="0.118" asserts="0">
                <categories>
                  <category name="mytag" />
                </categories>
                <properties>
                  <property name="Description" value="Add two numbers" />
                </properties>
                <reason>
                  <message><![CDATA[One or more step definitions are not implemented yet.
  StepDefinition1.GivenIHaveEnteredSomethingIntoTheCalculator(50)]]></message>
                </reason>
              </test-case>
            </results>
          </test-suite>
        </results>
      </test-suite>
    </results>
  </test-suite>
</test-results>
```

Output html looks like: 
[image: Output html looks like]

Comment: At some point, I found this was working fine with an older version of specflow. Just in case of somebody finds this a blocker.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate the step definitions by right-clicking on the feature's text and selecting "Generate Step Definitions"

This will generate the Steps class but it will have only stub methods that throw a `NotImplementedException`.

[image]

Comment: It is not related to question.
Question is about generating specflow reports. 
If you look at attached picture, you will see that there are only scenarios. 
I assume that 'show' link should be presented near each scenario.